# String pos in php does not work

Tags: php

I use the following to show some shipping methods:

```
foreach ($this->shipments_shipment_rates as $shipment_shipment_rates){
    if(is_array($shipment_shipment_rates)) {
        foreach ($shipment_shipment_rates as $shipment_shipment_rate) {
echo str_replace('name="virtuemart_shipmentmethod_id"', 'name="virtuemart_shipmentmethod_id" onclick="return ProOPC.setshipment(this);"', $shipment_shipment_rate);
            echo '<div class="clear"></div>';
        }
```

Now, if before the first echo i make an if condition like this:

```
$myvariable = echo str_replace('name="virtuemart_shipmentmethod_id"', 'name="virtuemart_shipmentmethod_id" onclick="return ProOPC.setshipment(this);"', $shipment_shipment_rate);
if (strpos ($myvariable, 3) !== false) {
    echo "I found my shipping method"
}
```

Then its like the strpos is always true. Even if inside $myvariable there is not the value 3. Any ideas?

Also can i for example hide a shipping method by doing this:

```
If(my_condition_with_strpos) {
    echo '<div style="display:none;">' . str_replace('name="virtuemart_shipmentmethod_id"', 'name="virtuemart_shipmentmethod_id" onclick="return ProOPC.setshipment(this);"', $shipment_shipment_rate) . '</div>'
}
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: why are you string-scanning for this? wouldn't the shipping method be available in a data structure somewhere, whatever was used to build this html in the first place?

Comment: `$myvariable = echo str_replace....`.... why the echo?

Comment: sorry i use the variable without echo but the foreach and the whole way of display is from a plugin and if i change this i need to change the whole plugin later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You search the value 3 as integer, see this example:

```
<?php
$string = 'asdsad';
$myvariable = str_replace('name="virtuemart_shipmentmethod_id"', 'name="virtuemart_shipmentmethod_id" onclick="return ProOPC.setshipment(this);"', $string);

if (strpos($myvariable, '3') !== false) {
    echo "I found my shipping method 1";
}
else {
    echo "Not found 1";
}

$string = '3';
$myvariable = str_replace('name="virtuemart_shipmentmethod_id"', 'name="virtuemart_shipmentmethod_id" onclick="return ProOPC.setshipment(this);"', $string);

if (strpos($myvariable, '3') !== false) {
    echo "<br>I found my shipping method 2";
}
else {
    echo "<br>Not found 2";
}
```

Comment: PHP will automatically convert the integer to a string.

Comment: I tryed to change to `strpos($myvariable, 3) !== false`  and didn't work

Comment: You're right. I just checked the documentation. If needle is an integer, it's treated as a character code, not a string. So it's like `strpos($myvariable, chr(3))`